# Javascript virtual keyboard: how to indentify text fields?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a Javascript virtual keyboard, and I would like it to appear everytime a user press enter on a text fields. But how can I know if a text (or any input) field is selected?

**--clarification**

I have to information or control over the page that will be loaded. I just want that, if a input field is selected and the user press enter, my virtual keyboard shows up.

**--update**

Does it makes any difference if what I'm trying to do is a firefox extension? (I think it shouldn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, for now, was use a specified key just to open the virtual keyboard when the user request.

Answer (score 3):

use jQuery and add the following

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //apply action to input elements by class
                //$("#.input_class").keypress(function(e) {
                //apply action to all input elements ( input, textarea, select and button )
                $(':input').keypress(function(e) {
                    if(e.keyCode==13){
                        // Enter pressed... do anything here...
                        alert($(this).val());
                    } else {
                                            //make shure you get the desired action for other keys pressed
                        xTriggered++;
                    }
                    //do not submit the form
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Comment: Note that you may also want to stop the event propagation, as in most browsers "Enter" in a form field will submit the form.

Comment: ".youre_input_class" means that I need to know the class of the input field? Becouse it's not my text field, is just any text field that appears in the browser...

Comment: @Piskvor , thanks for the heads up , @Tom check the update and the comments , you should be able to achive what you whant now .

Comment: Nothing happened with this code (with an alert on the keypress). I'm trying in google page.

Comment: quote from pages.google.com "Google Page Creator has been shutdown" , tested it right now and it works .

Comment: edited and made shure you can type inside input fields , allso i added an alert for the value if the element selected ( tested and works )

Answer (score 1):

bind it to the onfocus event. That event is triggered when the input element gets the focus. You could remove the keyboard again on the onblur event if you want to hide it again.

Comment: I don't have the component id. I want that when any input component on the page is focused, my virtual keyboard shows up.

Answer (score 0):

To get notified that a text field is selected, you could attach an event handler to `onfocus` of the fields you're interested in.

Example in jQuery (jQ chosen for brevity, the event works in plain JS):

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function(event){
    // do something here
});
```

If you only care to capture the "enter" key, you don't need to worry about focus, just attach to the onkeypress event of the textfields (see @poelinca's answer).

Comment: I don't have the component id. I want that when any input component on the page is focused, my virtual keyboard shows up.

Comment: @Tom Brito: The rule above matches any text input element, you don't need to know the component ID.

Comment: it's not recognizing still. What I'm doing is like an Firefox extension, but any javascript should work just fine (as had till now).

Answer (score 0):

Despite of what jquery apologetes say, there is no hassle to instrument all fields without resorting to large and slow external library:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++)
  for (var j = 0; j < document.forms[i].elements.length; j++)
    if (document.forms[i].elements[j].tagName.match(/^INPUT$/i))
      if (document.forms[i].elements[j].type.match(/^TEXT$/i))
        document.forms[i].elements[j].addEventListener('focus', function(){/* your stuff here */}, false);
```